proving using uniform convergence
I wanted to prove theorem 3 using uniform convergence. Should I show first for j= 0,1 before proving using the convergence? or can I directly prove the theorem?
enter image description here

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
